# Using gradle and the jfrog artifactory plugin how can I upload a generic artifact to a generic repository

Tags: gradle, build, artifactory, publish

I have a special build script that outputs an Alpine APK that I need to upload to a generic Artifactory repository.  How do I mark the apk output as an artifact that needs to be picked up and published?

Comment: https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CloudRepo repository, you could just POST with a curl. You might be able to do this with Artifactory.

Comment: Yea, and I may fall back to doing this I'd just like a DSL version using the Artifactory plugin.